# sbt val evaluated more than once

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm creating a `val` into my `build.sbt`, made of a random string, to be used in the `Setup` and `Cleanup` methods for scalatest, like this:

```scala
val foo = Random.alphanumeric.take(3).mkString
...
Test / testOptions += Tests.Setup(() => {
    // do stuff with it
})
...
Test / testOptions += Tests.Cleanup(() => {
    // do stuff with the same string
  }
```

but it seems that the two functions are actually re-evaluating the `val`, resulting in two different strings. It seems that the forking of the JVM (`fork := true`) does not play a role into it, so I'm kinda out of ideas. Is that intended and/or is there a way to fix it/finding another approach to the problem (native to Scala/sbt)?

Comment: Just an idea but maybe storing the `val` in an `object` in the meta build (`project` dir) can help?

Comment: Just another idea: does making it a `lazy val` changes anything ? It should be evaluated only once and stored.

Comment: `val foo = scala.util.Random.alphanumeric.take(3).mkString;
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(name := s"$foo SO $foo",version := s"0.1$foo")` does not has such problem: name="LM3 SO LM3", version="0.1LM3". Which version of sbt do you use?

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip unfortunately that does not help :(

Comment: @MikhailIonkin right now I'm using 1.6.2, but I guess that your snippet does work because there is just one evaluation, rather than the two that take place in my code

Comment: @GaëlJ unfortunately i'm not sure about what you do mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution was easier than thought:

```scala
lazy val foo = SettingKey[String]("foo", "Random string")
foo := Random.alphanumeric.take(3).mkString
```

and then call `foo.value` in the sbt code after